# Can you remove the previous landing pad once you got the bigger ones?

Tags: mars-horizon

In Mars Horizon the building space is limited. But each rocket requires a certain pad.

Can you remove the smaller landing pads once you have built a bigger one and still launch rockets that are of a smaller size than that pad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game considers the launch pads as an essential building, so they cannot be removed once placed and you need them to launch every mission.

You can remove the landing runway for the space shuttle though.

[image: screenshot showing the ingame message]